# UNIX Not in condition to file files

Tags: shell, unix

I have following files under one directory.

```
ABC_2019-01-01.zip  
ABC_2019-01-02.zip  
ABC_2019-01-03.zip  
.  
.  
.  
ABC_2019-01-31.zip   
.  
.  
XYZ_2019-01-01.zip  
XYZ_2019-01-02.zip  
XYZ_2019-01-03.zip  
.  
.  
.  
XYZ_2019-01-31.zip
```

suppose today's date is 2019-01-31 then I just want to retain today's ABC file i.e. ABC_2019-01-31.zip, retain all XYZ file (irrespective of date) and delete all ABC files which doesn't hold today's date.

Output should be:

```
ABC_2019-01-31.zip   
.   
.   
XYZ_2019-01-01.zip   
XYZ_2019-01-02.zip   
XYZ_2019-01-03.zip   
.   
.   
.   
XYZ_2019-01-31.zip
```

Comment: I think the question is "how do I remove all files named ABC_....zip except for ABC_2019-01-31.zip"?  But perhaps the question is "How do I make a glob that matches all files named ABC_....zip except for ABC_2019-01-31.zip"?  The former is easy, the latter is hard.  I'd be interested to see an answer for the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `$date` filled out:

```
date=$(date %+m-%d-%Y)
```

In bash you can use extended globs to exclude matches:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm ABC_!("$date").zip
```

Or in any shell you can use `find`:

```
find dir/ -name 'ABC_*.zip' ! -name "ABC_$date.zip" -delete
```

If `-delete` isn't available on your platform then use:

```
find dir/ -name 'ABC_*.zip' ! -name "ABC_$date.zip" -exec rm {} \;
```